# Windows: how can I set my PostgreSQL user to the superuser?

Tags: windows, postgresql, command-prompt

I am trying to create a database using PostgreSQL 9.4. I type "psql" in the command prompt, and then it asks for a password. I provide the password I set during the installation, but it says the authentication failed. After checking online, I concluded that I need to be using the superuser, named "postgres", which is the system user whose password is the one I set during the installation.

I am now trying to set PostgreSQL to this superuser. I spent a lot of time surfing the internet for a solution but wasn't able to solve the problem. I tried `postgres ALTER USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER` (I wrote that in the Windows command prompt), but it said that "alter" isn't recognized. Now, when I try to use PostgreSQL, **my main problem is that I get the error: "role MYUSERNAME does not exist".** (this is after I edited pg_hba.conf to make it not ask for a password)

Comment: Did you create a _myusername_ user with `CREATE USER/ROLE`?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo No, I didn't. According to my understanding, I never created a MYUSERNAME user; that's why it tells me that role does not exist. I created a postgres superuser during installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `psql` uses the name of the operating system to log in, to a database of the same name. If you want to log in as user `postgres` you should do:

```
psql -u postgres <any other options>
```

If a password is asked for, you give the password of the `postgres` user. You are now connected to the `postgres` database, where you really shouldn't be doing anything, except create new users (which are global to the installation) and other databases.

Once in the console, you can create new users like:

```
CREATE ROLE myusername LOGIN PASSWORD secret;
```

And new databases like:

```
CREATE DATABASE myowndb;
ALTER DATABASE myowndb OWNER TO myusername;
```

Then you log out from the console with `\q`.

In order to be able to access PostgreSQL using the new database, you have to edit the `pg_hba.conf` file (sample, modify to match your network settings):

```
host myowndb myusername 192.168.0.0/16 md5
```

Now you restart the PostgreSQL server from the `Services` tab in `Administrative tools` on the `Control Panel`.

Then you can log in to your new database:

```
psql -u myusername -d myowndb
```

Or use other clients like `pgAdminIII`.

Comment: @hashemelezabi: If you don't want to specify `-u postgres` (or `-u myusername`) each time, you can set the environment variable `PGUSER` which "overrides" the current username: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Your method works, and I was able to create a database. However, since I need to set it to user "postgres" everytime, I'm not able to execute other commands in the command prompt because if I exit the console using '\q', the user seems to be set back to MYUSER. Therefore, I want to set the PGUSER variable, @a_horse_with_no_name. But I'm not able to. What is the syntax that makes me set this variable?

Comment: @HashemElezabi: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=how%20to%20set%20an%20environment%20variable%20in%20windows

Comment: @HashemElezabi I do not understand exactly what your problem is. Once you have made a new user and a database with ownership to the new user you do not need the `postgres` user anymore. Anyway, you can set `PGUSER` as an Environment Variable: Start Menu, right-click on Computer, Properties..., Advanced System Settings (on Win 7 anyway).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Oh, I should set it that way. OK, I know how to set it but what should its value be?`postgres`? Thanks. Patrick: I created a new user (btw, `CREATE ROLE` gave me a syntax error, so I used `CREATE USER`), and I followed all your steps, but in the end it still said `role myuser does not exist`, although when I try `\du` to check the roles, I find `myuser`. From what u said I concluded that ppl don't use the `postgres` user; it's only used to create other users in the beginning. Am I correct?

Comment: It should be the username you want to use when calling `psql` - only you know which one that is. But from what you describe it most probably is `postgres`

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name! It is now set automatically to `postgres`, and my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

- Under Windows. The Postgres bin directory ships with the user commands **createuser.exe** and **dropuser.exe**.
- Say, if running initdb (effective fresh install) or for some other reason there is no superuser (like the question).
- Can also manage the users and superusers (-s option) with the above two commands. ie.

  ## Create the superuser called postgres:

  C:"Program Files"\PostgreSQL\15\bin\createuser.exe -s postgres

  ## Drop a user:

  C:"Program Files"\PostgreSQL\15\bin\dropuser.exe postgres